# LDAP Cassandra OpsCenter Configuration With AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, cassandra, opscenter, datastax-enterprise

I have an OpsCenter that I need to connect to AD. The relevant configuration below:

```
[authentication]
enabled = True
authentication_method = LDAP
audit_pattern = ldaplog

[ldap] 
server_host = ldap.very.chill.domain
server_port = 389 
uri_scheme = ldap
search_dn = CN=DSE OpsCenter LDAP,OU=Service Accounts,DC=very,DC=chill,DC=domain
search_password = duhsecure
user_search_base = OU=employees,DC=very,DC=chill,DC=domain
user_search_filter = (sAMAccountName={0})
group_search_base = OU=employees,DC=very,DC=chill,DC=domain
group_search_filter_with_dn = (member=cn={0},OU=employees,DC=very,DC=chill,DC=domain)
group_name_attribute = cn
group_search_type = directory_search 
admin_group_name = superemployees, superemployees2
protocol_version = 3
```

However, it gives me this error:

```
Failed to log in: User test has no defined roles in LDAP
```

I found [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/configure/troubleshootOpscLDAP.html) in the relation and made sure that sAMAccountName = test and the CN=test on AD side as instructed. Same error.

My knowledge of ldap is not very deep and does not allow me to see what else I might have wrong.

Also, when tried debugging ldap cummunications on opscenter side by running in foreground:

```
/usr/share/opscenter/bin/opscenter -f
```

Same error without any additional details follows.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.